# Best practice to implement secure database for android device

Tags: android, database, security, android-sqlite

I have implemented android database with sqlite and using content provider.

But the data in my database is not encrypted.

Is there any best practice to implement secure database for android device?

I mean not just encrypt but also any Technics that can improve security to my apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "secure database" you mean "a database whose data is encrypted via a passphrase that you get from the user", I recommend [SQLCipher for Android](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/).

Comment: I mean not just encrypt but also any Technics that can improve security to my apps. Thank you for your suggestion :) .

Comment: @um.anusorn: "but also any Technics that can improve security to my apps" -- there are entire *books* on that subject. If you are going to use StackOverflow, you need to ask *focused questions*.