# Secure sqlite database: Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlcipher-android

I want to secure my sqlite database. 
I searched a lot but ended up with the suggestions of using SQLCipher.

Is there any new advancement in this field other than SQLCipher?
Please suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20907327/3974530

Comment: @InsaneCat Shared link also suggests SQLCipher only.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `SQLCipher`, One thing you can do is encrypt your data before storing it in the database and decrypt it at runtime when populating it.

You can use a `encryption key` that you can store on `Firebase` and retrieve it from there at your app startup, this will add another layer of security to your encryption because the `key` will not be exposed inside the app if someone decompiles the app.

Comment: Store on Firebase- Doesn't that mean I need internet access all way around?

Answer (score 0):

I'm securing my database on my own, procedure is following:

1. [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) used as ORM (platform independent ORM over SQLite)
2. All sensible data stored in BLOB's
3. BLOB's secured using standard encryption technique, e.g. `com.madgag.spongycastle` works well under Android